# Clearing second set of X ticks matplot lib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to set my own ticks and labels on a plt plot, but can't seem to clear out one of the labels on the x axis. My code is below:

```
plt.close()
df['col_1'].plot()
df['col_2'].plot()
df['col_3'].plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: Labels On]

And my code to try and turn the x-axis labels off:

```
plt.close()
df['col_1'].plot()
df['col_2'].plot()
df['col_3'].plot()
plt.xticks(ticks=[], lables=[])
plt.show()
```

[image: Labels Off]

How do I get rid of the 3 instances of Jul on the x-axis? I set the x-axis label to 'Date'.

Comment: `Jul` is a minor ticklabel. You could `ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)`. However, if you want to set your custom ticks, you will have different problems, because you don't know the pandas units in use. Hence you will probably want to use the `x_compat` option when plotting, and then the offending labels won't be there from the start.

Comment: Ah yes! `ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)` worked. Ill post the working code as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) for the help. Since his was a comment I'm posting the working code below:

```
plt.close()
df['col_1'].plot()
df['col_2'].plot()
df['col_3'].plot()
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
plt.xticks(df.index.values[::2], df.index.values[::2], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I obviously have to clean up the labels some, but that's not super relevant to the question.

Comment: As commented, don't be surprised if this would not work with a different dataset, because you have no control over the internal units that pandas uses.

Comment: I'm not sure i get what you mean. Wouldn't I always be able to change the dtype for the index I'm using?

Comment: Depending on the granularity and regularity of a given datetime-like index, you might get a Period index or some other such specific type. This is a fairly common issue when plotting datetimes, at least with pandas, anyway.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm doing a fair amount of cleaning before I get to this stage, including forcing the data to be datetime. Thanks for the comment!